# Snowflake Column Nullability Changes by Primary Key Declaration Style

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, if I use create table and declare the primary key inside the create command, all columns in the primary key are automatically made "not null".  However, if I create a table without a primary key and use an alter table command to add a primary key, the nullable columns are not changed to "not null".

Is this considered a bug in Snowflake, or should I just assume that this is the expected behavior?

Leaves Column3 as nullable, even after creating primary key:

```
create  table Table1 (
Column1 TEXT(16777216),Column2 NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,Column3 NUMBER(38,0) IDENTITY START 3 INCREMENT 7,Column4 NUMBER(38,0) IDENTITY START 1 INCREMENT 1,Column7 NUMBER(38,0)
);

ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT Table1_PK PRIMARY KEY (Column2,Column3);
```

Forces Column3 to be "not null", even though column definition allows nullable, due to primary key:

```
create  table Table1 (
Column1 TEXT(16777216),Column2 NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,Column3 NUMBER(38,0) IDENTITY START 3 INCREMENT 7,Column4 NUMBER(38,0) IDENTITY START 1 INCREMENT 1,Column7 NUMBER(38,0)
, CONSTRAINT Table1_PK PRIMARY KEY (Column2,Column3)
);
```

Comment: PK constraints are not enforced in Snowflake.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table-constraint.html#constraint-properties

Comment: Specifically, the addition of a PK to a table already populated with information will not invalidate the data already present.

Comment: @Eric This case resembles a bit [CREATE TABLE Command: Change to Enforcement of PRIMARY KEYS created by Command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2021-06-bcr.html#create-table-command-change-to-enforcement-of-primary-keys-created-by-command). In the past your second example would also not have NOT NULL added for column3 during table creation. Here a situation is different as table already exists(and may contain data). It is a good observation.

Comment: @JimDemitriou, You are correct about PK constraints on standard Snowflake tables; however, PK's are not only enforced, but are mandatory for the new hybrid tables.  https://www.snowflake.com/blog/introducing-unistore/

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, this is interesting.  So, it looks like before that 2021 bug change, even the "create table" declaration of the constraint did not force the column to be non-null.  Since Snowflake publicly announced that that behavior was a bug, it makes me think that it is a bug for the "alter table" to not automatically apply the non-null constraint.

Comment: @Eric Please check my latest update on my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's expected behaviour, and I would suggest you report it to Snowflake Support although there is a very simple workaround.

The page referred by @Lukasz has a clear statement:

> In Snowflake, a PRIMARY KEY constraint is implemented as a NOT NULL
> constraint.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2021-06-bcr.html#create-table-command-change-to-enforcement-of-primary-keys-created-by-command

So if it was implemented as a NOT NULL constraint, then when you add a PK to an existing column, Snowflake should add the NOT NULL constraint.

**Final update: I see it's already reported as a "bug" (SNOW-549894). The development team recognized the defective behaviour, and it is planned to be fixed (no ETA) The intended behaviour is to not allow nulls in primary key columns.** To verify this information and ask for an update, you can submit a case to Support and refer to the number I provided.

Comment: It is expected behavior - please see the June 2021 release notes here:  https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/5-23-Behavior-Change-Release-Notes-June-21-22-2021#:~:text=In%20Snowflake%2C%20a%20PRIMARY%20KEY,level%20or%20the%20statement%20level.

Comment: I took the sentence from the page you refer: "In Snowflake, a PRIMARY KEY constraint is implemented as a NOT NULL constraint." What am I missing at that point? Why do you think defining a PK after creating the table should not add a NOT NULL constraint?

Comment: In the release notes, it states that the NOT NULL application occurs at the CREATE or REPLACE TABLE statement.  If you have an existing table, and want to change the column to be NOT NULL you need to execute an ALTER TABLE statement where you change that column's properties to NOT NULL.  Altering a table to have a PK will not change the key columns to convert to NOT NULL, nor will it enforce any PK behaviors (like prevent duplicate PKs).

Comment: Admittedly, Snowflake documentation could be clearer on this.  There are many who assume PK constraints act the same on Snowflake as they do on other RDBMs, and they don't.  if you want to prevent duplicate keys, you need to implement that programmatically.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see where the doc mentions that NOT NULL constraint will be applied only if we are creating the table. The doc doesn't mention anything about the behavioral difference between create table vs alter table. There is obviously a difference, but I don't think this is intended. There was a difference between statement-level and column-level PK definitions, but it was not intended either.

Comment: From the linked content in my answer, see the bullet that states "If you have tables that you have already created and that were intended to have an implied NOT NULL constraint but that might not have it, you might wish to execute an ALTER TABLE <table> ALTER COLUMN <primary_key_column> NOT NULL command to add the NOT NULL constraint. (This will give an error message if there are NULL values in the column, in which case you’ll typically want to update the NULL values and then re-try the ALTER TABLE.)"

Comment: As mentioned earlier, Snowflake documentation could be clearer.  Here is a link to the documentation on constraints that state the NOT NULL constraint can only be applied as an inline directive within the column definition: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table-constraint.html#usage-notes

Comment: @JimDemitriou It says "if you have tables created with statement-level PKs, you may want to run ALTER TABLE to add the NOT NULL constraint (to fix the situation). If the "NOT NULL" is missing, and the shortest way to fix, is to run "alter table" command. You may say "it didn't suggest to recreate because it won't help" but this would be an assumption.  I don't go with an assumption based on non-existing statements. The doc says "a PRIMARY KEY constraint is implemented as a NOT NULL constraint". So when we add a PK to a table, a "NOT NULL" should be defined.

Comment: Gokhan, the link Lucasz provided above states "a PRIMARY KEY constraint is implemented as a NOT NULL constraint" appears *under the heading* of CREATE TABLE Command: Change to Enforcement of PRIMARY KEYS created by Command .  That's the key point - the behavior for CREATE and ALTER are different.  The verbiage I provided is below that in the same Snowflake document - if the table already exists, you need to alter the column to NOT NULL.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2021-06-bcr.html#create-table-command-change-to-enforcement-of-primary-keys-created-by-command

Comment: @JimDemitriou I don't agree with you, and as you already explained your thoughts in your answer, I don't think we should keep discussing this in the comments.

Comment: FWIW - I work for Snowflake, and lead database migrations.  This behavior is expected, understood, and documented.  I do believe the documentation could be clearer, and I'll make a request to revise the documentation accordingly.

Comment: I see it's already reported as a "bug" (SNOW-549894). The development team recognized the defective behaviour, and it is planned to be fixed (no ETA) The intended behaviour is to not allow nulls in primary key columns.

Comment: I stand corrected - it was initially communicated to us as separate behavior between create and alter statements.

Answer (score 1):

Per comments above, this is expected behavior.

Please note there is a behavioral difference in the CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE vs ALTER TABLE statements here.

When creating a table, if a PK constraint is present in the CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE command, there the columns defined in the PK will have the NOT NULL attribute applied.

If a table already exists, an ALTER TABLE can add the PK, but will not change the underlying attributes of the columns in the PK nor enforce restrictions on the data present in the table.

You can issue a separate ALTER TABLE command to change the column attribute to NOT NULL on an existing table.

Please note, while Snowflake will enforce a NOT NULL on columns where that is defined at the column level, it will not enforce the PK constraint of preventing duplicate keys in the table (either historically or prospectively).

[https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/5-23-Behavior-Change-Release-Notes-June-21-22-2021#:~:text=In%20Snowflake%2C%20a%20PRIMARY%20KEY,level%20or%20the%20statement%20level](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/5-23-Behavior-Change-Release-Notes-June-21-22-2021#:%7E:text=In%20Snowflake%2C%20a%20PRIMARY%20KEY,level%20or%20the%20statement%20level)

Comment: I see it's already reported as a "bug" (SNOW-549894). The development team recognized the defective behaviour, and it is planned to be fixed (no ETA) The intended behaviour is to not allow nulls in primary key columns.

Comment: I stand corrected - it was initially communicated as separate behavior for alter and create statements.